# Typescript Angular 2 onchange url not changing content

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following code and when i am clicking on oost(:slug) it's display the wright content but when I click on zuid(:slug) there is no new content.
How can i achieve that?

Route:

```
{ path : ':slug' , name: 'Items' , component: DirectoryComponent},
```

DirectoryComponent:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.slug = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['slug'];
    this.dataService.fetchData(this.slug)
        .subscribe(
            (data) => {
         .......
    }
}
```

DataService:

```
fetchData(slug) {
    if (slug == '') {
        slug = 'home';
    }
    return this.http.get(ConfigService.API_URL + 'items/' + slug)
        .map(
            (res) => res.json()
        )
        ;
}
```

Answer:

constructor( public activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute, 
             private dataService:DataService, 
             private seoService:SeoService, 
             private router:Router ) {

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
    params => {
        this.dataService.fetchData(params['slug'])
            .subscribe(
                (data) => {
                 .....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
constructor( public activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute, 
             private dataService:DataService, 
             private seoService:SeoService, 
             private router:Router ) {

    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
        params => {
            this.dataService.fetchData(params['slug'])
                .subscribe(
                    (data) => {
                     .....
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're staying on the same route, but with a difference parameter. Angular will not recreate a new component in that case, but stay on the same one. You should thus not use the snapshot, but subscribe to the params observable of the activated route, and refresh the data when new params are emitted.

Comment: activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => ...)

Comment: So i have to replace this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['slug'] into your snippet and it works?

Comment: No. You have to understand what an observable is, what subscribing to an observable means, then to understand that activated route has a params observable that emits new params every time the parameters of the route change. Then adapt your code to subscribe to the observable in order to update the state of your component every time the params change. Reading the documentation helps a lot in this process. Experimenting helps a lot too. Copy and pasting code without understanding it doesn't help.